# RVM issues on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rvm

Hi I have gone through the installation of git, curl, RVM and Rails through Michael Hartl's railstutorial screencast and it worked last night.

However, this morning when I reopened my terminal and I checked the versions of both rails and git they were older than the release I installed and rvm was nowhere to be found. I have checked spotlight for rvm and it returns nothing. I only receive Rails version 2.3.5 and git 1.7.3.4 when it showed Rails 3.0.7 and Git 1.7.5.4 last night. Has anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: Did you set a default ruby installation (like `rvm --default 1.9.2`?)

Comment: Yes, I typed in rvm --create use 1.9.2@standard then rvm --default use 1.9.2@standard

Comment: rvm was no where to be found? After installing it once? Where was it originally? [as a note, RVM uses its own pathing stuffs so without using it to use your ruby, the paths might be off perhaps]

Comment: I ran bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm) then rvm install

Comment: After running that, did you close then reopen your terminal?

Comment: I ran:                                                          [TomCiopp]~$ type rvm | head -n1 it returned rvm is a function then
[TomCiopp]~$ gem install rails --version 3.0.7 then checked the version which said rails 3.0.7 and then I closed the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also put something in your .bashrc or equivalent in order to tell RVM to use the appropriate version of Ruby as a work around. For example if you are using 1.9.2-head, in your .bashrc you should have

`rvm use 1.9.2-head`

Alternatively, you can just use the above command whenever you need to use this version. Once you load the correct ruby version, rails should change to what you were using last night, you can check with

`ruby -v` and `rails -v`

To find rvm, look in ~/.rvm . It won't show up in spotlight, it's hidden.

Comment: if you just type into your terminal `rvm use 1.9.2` nothing happens at all? if you're getting an error there, try `rvm install 1.9.2` then repeat

Comment: I get rvm command not found for both requests, however there is a directory for rvm

Comment: and if you look in your ~/.bash_profile you have:  `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` ? If it's there trying running `source .bash_profile` again to ensure you're running the current version of your .bash_profile

Comment: export PS1 = "[MYNAME]\W$ " is all I have in the .bash_profile file

Comment: There's your issue. You need to open up your bash_profile and insert the above line. With that in there, close your session and open a new one. Then use `rvm use 1.9.2` that should now work.

Comment: Ok this finally worked, I added it last night but I may have forgotten to save the text in my .bash_profile or might have added it to the wrong file